# I'm trying to make my bot give a role to someone that uses the command but it says "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'"

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm a complete beginner so can someone please explain me what is wrong here and how to fix it? Thank you

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get


@client.command()
async def reserve(message, *, stand):
        channel = message.channel,
        author = message.author,
        guild = message.guild,
        the_world = get(message.guild.roles,name="The World"),
        if stand == 'The World':
            await message.author.add_roles(the_world)


The error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: Make sure your question title describes the actual problem.  Do not put `I'm a complete beginner and I don't understand what's wrong here` as a question title.  That is useless to anyone else.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming as the rest of your bot runs, your provided code causes this error as you are using `get(ctx.guild.roles,name="The World")` instead,  make sure to use `discord.utils` in your argument:

`discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,name="The World")`

Additionally I've modified some more of your code, as a command, you don't need to pass `message` as your parameters, use `ctx` and it's attributes.

```py
@client.command()
async def reserve(ctx, *, stand):
        if stand == 'The World':
            the_world = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,name = "The World"),
            await ctx.author.add_roles(the_world)
```

Comment: I tried what you said but it still gives the same error "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'"